# Ask for Recommendation for Biking Outfits

Tags: shorts

I am thinking about start cycling other than just riding it around school. I want to make myself look professional. Do you have any advice for me? I don't really know what kind of outfit is suitable for college students. I think I would love to get a shirt or a tank and a bicycle shorts. Thank you in advance. Does bikers have special shoes, too?

Comment: ......I don't really know what kind of outfit is suitable for college students..... Aw jeez, man, I'm forever banging on at my daughter that she's there to learn, it doesn't matter what she looks like ;-) Seriously, just look around the web at what is available - when I started road cycling I hit a couple of chinese web sites selling....er...."replica" team kit (right down to the Made in Italy signs) to get me started. A lot cheaper than going to a bike shop, not as good quality, but got me started.

Comment: And yes there are special shoes, they go along with special pedals. If you go for these, go to a bike shop and get a proper fit. But there are also flat pedals which do not require special shoes.

Comment: I still use the Chinese bike jerseys and shorts from eBay.  I can't justify the price difference.  If there was something in between paying $20 for bib shorts on eBay, and paying $100+ at my LBS for bib shorts,  I would gladly support my LBS. But the price for shorts an shirt is easily 3 times as expensive if I choose to buy local.

Comment: Whatever you do, I am compeled to refer you to "the rules "http://www.velominati.com/the-rules/

Comment: Whatever you do, as well as what @mattnz says, please post a photo when you get your kit

Answer (score 6):

It's not really clear what you mean by *look professional*.

If you mean a professional cyclist, then a cycling outfit is the way to go. They are designed to be comfortable for cycling, and to keep your leg muscles warm.

But if you mean professional as in office worker professional, then that's a problem that many of us struggle with.

Firstly, how far do you ride? The further you ride, the more likely it is that your clothes will be sweaty and you'll want to change. If it's not that far, in warm weather many biking students here wear long baggy shorts and matching tops, like skateboarders. But you wouldn't say they look professional.

The other way to go is to change clothes. Depending on the size of your campus and how modern it is, it likely has a decent gym with showers, and maybe locker facilities. Many students take gym membership to access those facilities; you can keep a change of clothes, and a towel there, and shower and change before classes.

Comment: If it is not clear what the question is then why are you answering?

Comment: The OP is a new user and seeking help. I like to provide what help I can where I have particular knowledge, and be welcoming. Who knows, maybe in future the OP will be one of our community's leaders :-)

Comment: But how would a comment not have promoted that same spirit?

Comment: My feeling was that the comments were going a different way to the way I saw it. IMO it doesn't work well when the comments have more than one conversation thread.

Comment: There are also bicycling shorts and what not you can wear all day, but it sounds like OP probably wants team kit and stuff.